# how to count the number of spaces in a string and replace all of them with the count in the first occurance of it

Tags: java

/* Here the code doesnot run properly and does not count the number of spaces in the string and replace those spaces with the number of occurance in the first string*/

```
String ip=sc.nextLine();
int count=0;
System.out.println("string");
String[] str=ip.split(" ");
for(int i=0;i<ip.length();i++){
    boolean flag=true;
    for(int k=0;k<i;k++){
        if(ip.charAt(i)==ip.charAt(k))
        flag=false;
        if(flag){
            for(int j=0;j<ip.length();j++){
                if(ip.charAt(i)==ip.charAt(j)){
                    count=count+1;
                }
                if(count>2){
                    System.out.println(ip.charAt(i)+""+count);
                    count=0;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println(ip.charAt(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: give us an in/out example

Comment: `String#split` and `String#replaceAll` would by first port of call, but if  "you're not allowed to use those", then I'd also consider a `StringBuilder` and possibly a `StringJoiner` ... but you probably can't use those either :/

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of replace and replaceFirst with two identical Strings

```
    String withSpaces = "this is a test with spaces";
    String copy = withSpaces;
    copy = copy.replace(" ", "");
    int num = (withSpaces.length() - copy.length());
    withSpaces = withSpaces.replaceFirst(" ", "" + num);
    System.out.println(withSpaces);
```

**output**

this5is a test with spaces

**edit**

To get rid of the other spaces after this simply change to

```
withSpaces = withSpaces.replaceFirst(" ", "" + num).replace (" ", "");
```

Comment: withSpaces = withSpaces.replaceFirst(" ", "" + num); this is correct....but there is still a small work in the program....now i need to delete all those spaces except the first occurance.

Comment: well after `replaceFirst` then do another `replace (" ", "");` **edited the answer**

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the following code to count the number of spaces in a
>   particular String and then replace all spaces with count.

**Code :**

```
  String testwithspaces = "this is the string with spaces";
        System.out.println("Orignal String :"+testwithspaces);
        int count = testwithspaces.length() - testwithspaces.replace(" ", "").length();
        System.out.println("Number of spaces ="+count);
        String replaceSpaceWithCount= testwithspaces.replace(" ",""+count);
        System.out.println("String with space replaced by count : "+replaceSpaceWithCount);
```

**Output :**

```
Orignal String :this is the string with spaces
Number of spaces =5
String with space replaced by count : this5is5the5string5with5spaces
```

You have to use two replace statement over here :

- to count the number of spaces.
- to replace spaces with that count.